# Name / type of image filter

Tags: numerical-optimization, image-processing

Occasionally I stumble across a very pretty image filter and I always wonder what the underlying algorithm is. The term wavelet-transformation pops up in my head but my searches let to nothing.

It appears using solid colors ..
[image: wo_grading]
.. and linear color grading.
[image: with_grading]

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: Is that a doug?

Comment: @BobDobbs You mean the Ramer–Douglas–Peucker algorithm?

Comment: great question - no clue. looks vaguely like a Voronoi Diagram where the vertices are selected using edge/image gradient data. You might have better luck in [signal processing stack exchange](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/)